# javascript - add a js confirm to mailto link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mailto, confirm

Is there a way with javascript to automatically have the page look for any mailto links and then have it fire off an confirm dialog when a user clicks on the mailto link?

From this site I found a way to do so for an alert. I am beyond a novice with javascript.

We need to warn people not to include confidential information in the their email without having an existing relationship.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="mailto:name@domain.com">Email Link</a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('a[href^="mailto"]').on('click',
function() {
alert('This is some alert text');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/j75FL/1/)

try this:

```
$('a[href^="mailto"]').on('click',
function() {
  return confirm('Do you want to send email?');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a `confirm` function in javascript.

```
$('a[href^="mailto"]').on('click',
function() {
  if (!(confirm('This is some alert text'))) {
     return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript confirm dialog

```
$('a[href^="mailto"]').on('click', function() {
    return confirm('your question');
});
```

Comment: There is no need to alert after the text is confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

you can make it a one liner without jquery:

```
<a href="mailto:name@domain.com" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Email Link</a>
```